# Flattening a maple woodblock by hand for fine art woodcut printing on a press

Tags: wood, technique, hand-tools, sanding, hand-planing

I have had considerable problems trying to flatten maple woodblocks by hand for printing on an etching press.

I often print with a jig below the block to allow me to register multiple colors -- the jig may not be completely flat, but I don't think that is the main problem. The roller on an etching press is extremely precise, so the block must be incredibly flat, otherwise shallow areas will not print (see trial prints, also 2 prints with different pressures).

Before chiselling in a design, a perfect rectangle must be able to be printed; which often proves elusive. It's fairly easy to flatten smaller sizes, but as the size of the block increases, the more difficult it is to flatten a block. My blocks are relatively small, though.

After initial experiences with warping, I was able to order quarter-sawn and rift-sawn Maple and allow them to acclimate to the humidity where I work, which has worked out; much less warping. I use the maple because of the detail.

I have tried a wide variety of techniques. I've gotten better with a Stanley #4 hand plane, but I get some pockmarks, although the edges come out crisp and square. Invariably, if I try to flatten the block with sandpaper wrapped around plexiglass, the edges will become rounded no matter what I do.

I've come to realize I'd have to work on a larger block, then cut it down on a table saw to avoid rounding of the edges. I've tried adding wood and/or tape to the bottom of the block (a technique called "make-ready," image attached) and planing from the bottom as well.

I am aware of jointers and planers and their differences; they're just a bit beyond my budget presently. Someone suggested a belt sander, which might be cheaper but not sure if that would round off the edges.

[image: trial prints]
[image: flattening with sandpaper under plexi]
[image: 2 different printing pressures]
[image: "make-ready" technique - adding material to back of block]

Comment: my first this would be why not put the sand paper on a piece of glass/plexi-glass and move the wood block against that?  if you have a big enough piece of sand paper stuck down (on a flat surface) you shouldn't round the edges by moving the block flat against it.  The edges round because move the sand paper over the wood, it wraps around the block just a little bit.   I've found it easier to flatten wood by doing it this way and you can get some pretty sharp edges.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it with the woodblock on top, taping the sandpaper down, but I find it also seems to round the wood on the edges for some reason.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking! Getting an absolutely flat, and flawless, surface by hand in a wood as hard as maple is actually quite difficult (understatement) — our general standard for "flat" isn't clinically flat/level, it's flat enough that a surface looks and/or feels flat, which despite appearances is a huge step below what I think you need. I think sanding *is* actually THE way to do it at the end of the day (with planing to get you close to the end result) but it's still a ton of work. This would be far *far* less onerous using one or more machine tools to help.

Comment: *"I've gotten better with a Stanley #4 hand plane, but I get some pockmarks"* I think you're describing tearout and that should be 99% conquerable if your no. 4 is one of the better ones (this is semi-random) and it's tuned and set up correctly. There's abundant advice here (and elsewhere!) on how to get a smoother to produce the best results it's capable of, starting with the fettling the cap iron and then setting it very close. Note: you can pretty much ignore everything that says you want to set the frog forward, the cap-iron effect completely trumps a tight mouth for tearout control.

Comment: *"but I find it also seems to round the wood on the edges for some reason"* Any give, any at all, in the abrasive will tend to 'dub' or round over arrises and corners. The abrasive must be adhered in some manner to a dead-flat surface for this to work as well as it can.

Comment: Thanks to all the suggestions and the welcome! My Stanley #4 plane is an excellent model. I still don't completely understand the two knobs in the back that affect the top and bottom of the rear of the blade. Sometimes the plane shaves wonderfully and other times I'm clearly not doing something right, getting tear-out. I do sharpen the blade at intervals. I'll look up the further plane pointers on the forum and study the plane suggestion. I'm thinking I may have to break down and buy some sort of less expensive, small jointer-planer at some point.

Comment: Used thickness planers are often quite reasonably priced, as would the option of finding someone with a machine and borrowing time.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into used and new small jointers, planers & combos.

Comment: A decent local commercial cabinet shop should have a planer and they might be willing to prepare your blocks for you, especially if there is an interesting print in it for them in the future.

Comment: This is quite a ways down the road for you but worth mentioning this now as it's an an important safety note re. planing, you have to be *extremely cautious* about planing too-short pieces. There's a minimum safe length to plane so for something like this it would be good practice to start with boards say 3x the required final size (overlength), plane those down, do any final sanding and then cut to final length on the TS. You can minimise sanding BTW by ending with the thinnest skims off the boards the machine will allow. All together you'll save perhaps >95% of the current sanding time.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Thanks for the safety tips. I had visited a carpenter a few months ago, who has a planer and jointer. For safety reasons he wouldn't feed in small pieces, but would order a plank and do the jointing and/or planing on that, cutting it down into smaller pieces afterwards. That might cost a good chunk of what a thickness planer, mini-jointer or combo would cost. I do respect safety protocols. I would prefer to leave serious power tools to a professional, though. I still have a bunch of small, rough quarter-sawn and rift-sawn pieces; one of the reasons was still tending towards working by hand.

Comment: To narrow down my question, I’m thinking printing's been around since the 15th century, so I'm guessing people might have found a way to flatten blocks very well with relatively basic tools in the old days, although they might have also printed their woodcuts with more forgiving techniques such as hand-burnishing. So, my basic questions are...

Comment: 1) Getting an opinion on ordering, say, a piece of metal flat stock with impeccable flatness and securing a piece of sandpaper to it, sanding with the woodblock on top of the sandpaper, as previously suggested. I’m not sure if metal flat stock would be much more flat than industrial plexiglass. If I glue a piece of sandpaper to the metal flat stock, it would be hard to get off, making reuse of the somewhat expensive metal difficult. I’m not sure taping sandpaper around the edges to the flat stock would flatten the sandpaper enough.

Comment: 2) If I choose to go the power tool route, I understand that jointers flatten the top of a board and planers follow the contour of the bottom somehow. – so, do I really want a thickness planer if what I really would need is a mini-jointer? Or do I really need a combo? I've seen videos on router setups, but they seem too space-intensive. Thanks for any further advice.